# Is there a way where I can use MAX(Count(some_table_name)) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unsure how to find the maximum of a count function, for example

```sql
Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) as MaxTicketsBooked
, Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
From Seat_Reservation
Group By Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
Having Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) = (
    Select MAX(MaxTicketsBooked)
    From (
        Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) As MaxTicketsBooked
        From Seat_Reservation
        Group By Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
    ) As Maxed
);
```

This code works for me, however, I need to display CustomerNames which produces the error: Column 'Seat_Reservation.Customer_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Is there a way in which I could find the maximum of the count produced by

```
Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) as MaxTicketsBooked,
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a dummy aggregate like `min(CustomerName)`. Presumably all customers with the same phone number have the same name here.

Comment: Or use `with data as (select *, count() over (partition by customer_phone) as cnt from Seat_Reservation) select top 1 with ties from data order by cnt desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the code that failed, so I'll guess:

```
Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) as MaxTicketsBooked
, Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
, Seat_Reservation.Customer_name
From Seat_Reservation
Group By Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
Having Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) = (
    Select MAX(MaxTicketsBooked)
    From (
        Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) As MaxTicketsBooked
        From Seat_Reservation
        Group By Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
    ) As Maxed
);
```

And the error message makes perfect sense.

```
Column 'Seat_Reservation.Customer_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

The solution is right in the error message.

```
Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) as MaxTicketsBooked
, Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
, Seat_Reservation.Customer_name
From Seat_Reservation
Group By Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
, Seat_Reservation.Customer_name
Having Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) = (
    Select MAX(MaxTicketsBooked)
    From (
        Select Count(Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone) As MaxTicketsBooked
        From Seat_Reservation
        Group By Seat_Reservation.Customer_phone
    ) As Maxed
);
```